# Is All In Pre Flop the new Poker?

Tags: all-in, pre-flop, sit-and-go

I have been playing poker everyday these last weeks. And I have noticed that a lot of people are playing all in pre flop. Am I missing something here? Is this soms new way of playing now? Or is this something that has to do with sitngo?

I'm playing sitngo's of 10 dollar. Sitting at the table I see almost everybody is going All in pre flop the whole game. Just gambling on nice cards. Sometimes low pockets.Sometimes Suited. Not even connected. No one is trying to read. Or just play the game. Slowplay or something. I see this more and more everyday.
The sad story is, that most of the time they got lucky too. Just gambling on luck.
Dont get me wrong. I have been winning these couple of weeks. But this is something that frustrates me a lot. Cause in my opinion its takes the joy of playing away. And it forces me also to do this. If I wanted to gamble I would play Roulette or something else.

I'm curious to know your opinion.

Thanks

Comment: this could depend on stack sizes in the sit-n-gos, but depending on the stakes you play a lot of players will do this to gamble or just mess around. Don't feel like you are not able to play the game because of it, there is a lot of math/strategy around all-ins preflop and studying it can greatly improve your game. Just because they are gambling doesn't mean you have to, it's also hard to not get frustrated when players seem to get lucky a lot but it is something very useful to practice.

Comment: No. It's not at all

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not playing freerolls, you are probably playing hyper turbo with shallow stacks and fast structure, right?

If that is the case, going all-in or folding is perfectly normal since most of it starts with 10bb, and you do not have any room for postflop play either way. This is mathematically based [push fold chart](https://www.mypokercoaching.com/push-fold-chart/), so take a look at it and see what hands you should be shoving yourself and when.

If you are not playing hyper-turbo format and still see players moving all-in every hand in standard structure, just let me know where these games are, and I am heading that way! :)

If you want to play more REAL poker, simply play slower structure games, and you will surely have enough room to try your moves.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing new about that. It was common when I would play on Zynga several years ago, and it was common in play money tournaments, over 10 years ago, when I played on Full Tilt. I don't recall it as much in cash tournaments, but that's not to say it didn't happen at small stakes.